# how would one get an input horizontally in java using scanner class to count the string input

Tags: java, printing, user-input

i am not very skilled at programming and was wondering how would one get a input from a user horizontally instead of vertical?: basically like this.
abcd instead of

```
a
b
c
d
```

"Just to clear up i wanted to count how many string letters they typed,
i realized that i could use one scanner class but i wanted to see if they inputted nth        number of string and limit them from entering more!!!!"

Comment: What purpose does this serve?

Comment: If you are able to read entire line then just read all lines and concatenate them. Where is the problem here?

Comment: i'd have to shove em in an array and then look at them separately and was just wondering if you could do it an easier way. thought it made sense but i guess not.

Comment: the question seems off, you were asking how can users pass you data horizontally, which doesn't really mean much.  It looks like you are asking how to format said data.

Comment: yes that is what i am asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   String input = "";

    while (in.hasNext()) {

        input += in.next();

    }
    in.close();
```